# Do I have to mount redux-form to the "form" key in the root of my state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

The [getting started page](http://redux-form.com/6.0.1/docs/GettingStarted.md/) says:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form'

const reducers = {
  // ... your other reducers here ...
  form: formReducer     // <---- Mounted at 'form'
}
const reducer = combineReducers(reducers)
const store = createStore(reducer)
```

But the [reduxForm() documentation](http://redux-form.com/6.0.1/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/) says:

> **form : String [required]**
>
> the name of your form and the key to where your form's state will be mounted under the redux-form reducer

I am running the [Simple Form example](http://redux-form.com/6.0.1/examples/simple/). I have this code:

```
var reduxFormReducer = reduxForm({
  formKey: 'personal'  // a unique identifier for this form
})(SimpleForm);

var reducer = combineReducers({
  formKey: reduxFormReducer
});
```

But it shows this error:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Required prop `form` was not specified in `Form(SimpleForm)`. in Form(SimpleForm) (created by Connect(Form(SimpleForm)))

I've tried this:

```
var reduxFormReducer = reduxForm({
  form: 'formKey'  // a unique identifier for this form
})(SimpleForm);

var reducer = combineReducers({
  formKey: reduxFormReducer
});
```

It doesn't show that error but the edit fields are empty and can't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Hope your missed in reducer, please use the key name as `form`

```
var reduxFormReducer = reduxForm({
  form: 'formKey'  // a unique identifier for this form
})(SimpleForm);

var reducer = combineReducers({
  form: reduxFormReducer // <- change formKey to form here 
});
```

refer: http://redux-form.com/6.0.2/docs/GettingStarted.md/

**Update:**

The form reducer. Should be given to mounted to your Redux state at `form`.

If you absolutely must mount it somewhere other than `form`, you may provide a `getFormState(state)` function to the `reduxForm()` decorator, to get the slice of the Redux state where you have mounted the `redux-form` reducer.

Comment: that works, but the question is do I *have to* use *form*? I want to use something else like *state.foo" instead.

Comment: @AlexStack please check the updated answer, it would helpful ?